# Is it safe to delete other language lproj from apps?

Tags: applications, language

I cannot speak any language besides English, so all the other built in languages in many apps (including built in apps) serve no purpose on my disk. Is it safe to delete them, or will the app try to find them for whatever reason and panic and break if they are not found?

Would it be safe to delete the selected files in `Safari.app/Contents/Resources`?[image]

Comment: How much space would be saved by deleting these resources?

Answer (score 1):

Up to macOS 10.14 Mojave, it's *mostly* safe to delete any unwanted `*.lproj` folders — and also unwanted folders in a `locale/` folder. As you say, that can bring big wins in disk space, as language-specific resources form a significant part of the disk usage of many apps.

But there are some caveats:

- A few resources are not language-specific, and must not be deleted, e.g. `Base.lproj`/`base.lproj`, `Codes`, `Maketext`, and (possibly) `OpenCL.strings.lproj`.  (Those are the only ones I've seen, but there may of course be many others.)
- A very small number of apps check and refuse to start if *any* files are changed, e.g. Amadeus Pro, iPartition, and the Sparkle framework. (Again, there may be many others.)
- System Integrity Protection (SIP) prevents you from changing system apps. (It does no harm to try; you just get an error.)

I wrote a script to remove unwanted language files, which I've used for many years. For safety, it deletes only language folders it recognises and knows aren't needed; it leaves any English files along with those mentioned above, and shows a warning for any it doesn't recognise. (I learned that the hard way, when an earlier OS upgrade first introduced `Base.lproj` and my previous script broke everything…)

I can't yet vouch for macOS 10.15 Catalina or above — though early indications on macOS 12 Monterey suggest that the same may apply there too.

Comment: At least from Big Sur onwards, you won't be able to remove language files from the default applications any longer (at least not withouth going through a lot of steps with each system update).

Comment: @gidds What indications on Monterey as I agree with nohillside it would be tricky and not just a simple deletion - the whole bundle is now signed to check if it has been corrupted

Comment: As I said, you haven't been able to update system apps/programs for ages (since 10.11 El Capitan), due to SIP — the mechanism for that may have changed in Big Sur, but the effect is the same. As for Monterey: I've had my new MBP for only two days, so it's too early to be sure! But the script ran successfully on it, removed language files from a few apps I'd updated, and they still run fine. So it looks good so far.

Comment: The answer may benefit from an explanation about the type of applications for which this actually works.

Comment: Really, there's no reason to bother doing this.  You are not going to save enough space to matter, and will probably negatively impact the code signatures on installed applications.

Comment: @MarcWilson When I first did this (back when it worked for system apps too) IIRC it saved something like 10GB of disk space. It'd be less without the system apps, of course, but if you have many other apps it could still be quite significant.

Comment: @nohillside Is it not clear already? All apps _except_ the system ones, and a small number of others.